# Replace Head Stylesheet Path in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

I have the following HEAD tag

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link id="css1" href="demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

What I want to be able to in Javascript is somehow

```
document.head.children["css1"].href = "demo2.css";
```

Any ideas, I would like to be able to the change by id as there might be more tags in the head

Answer (score 5):

In a `script` tag anywhere *after* that `link`, you can indeed update its `href`:

```
document.getElementById("css1").href = "demo2.css";
```

Normally, it's best to put your `script` tags at the end, just before the closing `</body>` tag. In your case, since you're changing CSS, to avoid having the previous styling "flashing" at the user, you might want it higher up so it's handled sooner, though.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Change-Style-Sheet-Using-Tutorial-CSS-Swap-Stylesheet) shows you how to do that:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/svod51h1/)

javascript

```
function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {
  document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
```

html

```
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">

<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('1.css')">1 Style Sheet</button>
<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('2.css')">2 Style Sheet</button>
<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('2.css')">3 Style Sheet</button>
```